# How to get an existing webhook (parse from json) from Calendly?

Tags: c#, json, hook, calendly

I am new to StackOverflow, struggling to find a solution to my problem: I am trying to synchornize my asp.net app with the calendly api.

So far, I have managed to create a webhook subscription and I saw that the webhooks are being registered to  https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks/ and I was able to acces a specific webhook using its id (I used Postman to see all this, as I am currently local developing). I am having a lot of trouble since I am not able to understand what call should I make in order to get the webhooks and be able to use their data in my app.

https://developer.calendly.com/docs/sample-webhook-data
This is what I should be parsing, according to Calendly documentation.

I want to get data such as the emails of those participing into the event, also the date and status of the event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems to me there might be a lack of conceptual understanding of what webhooks are.

As you mention, you had already subscribed to be notified if some event happens in Calendly (I assume `invitee.created` event).

This means, that

1. when this event actually happens on Calendly (you may need to make a test scheduling request in the Calendly UI), **the notification about this event is sent to the URL you had registered (subscribed)**.
2. This registered URL has to be reachable for the notification call. In other words, **if the URL is in your local environment (and you mentioned it is so), it's impossible for the notification to reach the registered (subscribed) destination**. So this might be the issue you're experiencing.
3. You need to read incoming raw data. In my script, with PHP, I do it using `file_get_contents('php://input')`
4. You need to parse the data. With PHP I use `json_decode($inputData)`. In your language you've got to use whatever tools you have for JSON parsing.

Basically, that's it. In my case, I read invitee email using `$parsedData->payload->invitee->email`.

Hope it helps.